# Set MVC3 parameters to default if empty or null in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am struggling to default `CId` and `SId` to 1 if the parameters are empty,

```
  public ViewResult Index(int? CId,int?SId,string name,int? p)
    {

        if (CId == 0 || SId == 0)
        {
            CId = 1;
            SId = 1;
        }
```

Then I will use the values for a normal query. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cid` and `Sid` is [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), so you can use [HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) property to check if the variable has value or not (null)

```
  public ViewResult Index(int? CId,int?SId,string name,int? p)
  {
        if (!CId.HasValue || !SId.HasValue)
        {
            CId = 1;
            SId = 1;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious but have you tried:

```
public ViewResult Index(string name,int? p,int? CId = 1,int? SId = 1)
    {


    }
```

You have to rearrange them, because the default valued parameters have to come last. Also, being that they're nullable, I'm not actually sure if this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can follow the logic in the other one and have tested it and it has worked.  Did not test yours though